# httpd start fails and shows up error

Tags: apache

While i try to install server through `yum install httpd` and later when i start service it shows up following error :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable httpd.service 
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service' 
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start httpd.service 
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Can any body please help on it??

Comment: have you tried `service httpd start` ?

Comment: you can ask this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah tried that too.. the same error again :( ok i'll poost over there.thank u